# PHP/Cpanel - How to create cPanel accounts without 3rd party application?

Tags: php, automation, cpanel, whm

Good evening SO Community,

I've been trying to figure out how to dynamically create a cPanel account with PHP. While doing my pre-question research, I noticed that this question was asked quite a few times, and had a few answers. Unfortunately, the answers that I have found seem to have been depreciated in the latest cPanel versions. I have been trying to get the below script working but had no luck. **NOTE: I DID NOT CREATE THE SCRIPT, I JUST FORGOT THE SOURCE.** If you know of any way to create cPanel accounts with hosting packages, PLEASE let me know!

```
<?php

###############################################################
# cPanel WHM Account Creator 1.1
###############################################################
# Visit http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/ for updates
###############################################################
# Required parameters:
# - domain - new account domain
# - user - new account username
# - password - new account password
# - package - new account hosting package (plan)
# - email - contact email
#
# Sample run: create-whm-account.php?domain=reseller.com&user=hosting&password=manager&package=unix_500
#
# If no parameters passed then input form will be shown to enter data.
#
# This script can also be run from another PHP script. This may
# be helpful if you have some user interface already in place and 
# want to automatically create WHM accounts from there.
# In this case you have to setup following variables instead of
# passing them as parameters:
# - $user_domain - new account domain
# - $user_name - new account username
# - $user_pass - new account password
# - $user_plan - new account hosting package (plan)
# - $user_email - contact email
#
###############################################################

///////  YOUR WHM LOGIN DATA
$whm_user   = "root";      // reseller username
$whm_pass   = "PASS";  // the password you use to login to WHM

#####################################################################################
##############          END OF SETTINGS. DO NOT EDIT BELOW    #######################
#####################################################################################

$whm_host   = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

function getVar($name, $def = '') {
  if (isset($_REQUEST[$name]))
    return $_REQUEST[$name];
  else
    return $def;
}

// Domain name of new hosting account
// To create subdomain just pass full subdomain name
// Example: newuser.zubrag.com
if (!isset($user_domain)) {
  $user_domain = getVar('domain');
}

// Username of the new hosting account
if (!isset($user_name)) {
  $user_name = getVar('user');
}

// Password for the new hosting account
if (!isset($user_pass)) {
  $user_pass = getVar('password');
}

// New hosting account Package
if (!isset($user_plan)) {
  $user_plan = getVar('package');
}

// Contact email
if (!isset($user_email)) {
  $user_email = getVar('email');
}

// if parameters passed then create account
if (!empty($user_name)) {

  // create account on the cPanel server
  $script = "http://{$whm_user}:{$whm_pass}@{$whm_host}:2086/scripts/wwwacct";
  $params = "?plan={$user_plan}&domain={$user_domain}&username={$user_name}&password={$user_pass}&contactemail={$user_email}";
  $result = file_get_contents($script.$params);

  // output result
  echo "RESULT: " . $result;
}
// otherwise show input form
else {
$frm = <<<EOD
<html>
<head>
  <title>cPanel/WHM Account Creator</title>
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
</head>
<body>
  <style>
    input { border: 1px solid black; }
  </style>
<form method="post">
<h3>cPanel/WHM Account Creator</h3>
<table border="0">
<tr><td>Domain:</td><td><input name="domain" size="30"></td><td>Subdomain or domain, without www</td></tr>
<tr><td>Username:</td><td><input name="user" size="30"></td><td>Username to be created</td></tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input name="password" size="30"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Package:</td><td><input name="package" size="30"></td><td>Package (hosting plan) name. Make sure you cpecify existing package</td></tr>
<tr><td>Contact Email:</td><td><input name="email" size="30"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3"><br /><input type="submit" value="Create Account"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
EOD;
echo $frm;
}

?>
```

Please let me know if you need any more information!

Thank you in advance,
Tim

**EIDT**
Source: https://github.com/Ephygtz/cPanel-WHM-automated-account-creator/blob/master/create-whm-account.php

Any ideas?

Comment: The source was: https://github.com/Ephygtz/cPanel-WHM-automated-account-creator/blob/master/create-whm-account.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good afternoon,

I know this questions is a little dated, but I have found a solution that works for me. Please see below.

```
<?php
    Function createAccount ($newDomain = "", $newUser = "", $newPass = "", $newPlan = "", $newEmail = "") {
        $whm_user = "usename";
        $whm_pass = "password";
        $whm_host = "example.com";

        $newDomain = fixData($newDomain);
        $newUser = fixData($newUser);
        $newPlan = fixData($newPlan);

        If (!empty($newUser)) {
            // Get new session ID
            $sessID = newSession($whm_host, $whm_user, $whm_pass);

            $script = "https://www." . $whm_host . ":2087" . $sessID . "/scripts/wwwacct";
            $sData = "?plan={$newPlan}&domain={$newDomain}&username={$newUser}&password={$newPass}&contactemail={$newEmail}";

            // Authenticate User for WHM access
            $context = stream_context_create(array(
                'http' => array(
                    'header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("{$whm_user}:{$whm_pass}"),
                ),
            ));

            // Get result
            $result = file_get_contents($script.$sData, false, $context);
            //Echo "URL: " . $script.$sData . "<br /><br />";
            // Echo "Result: " . $result;

        } Else {
            Echo "Error: Username is empty!";
        }
    }


    Function newSession($nHost, $nUser, $nPass) { // Example details
        $ip = $nHost;
        $cp_user = $nUser;
        $cp_pwd = $nPass;
        $url = "https://$ip:2087/login";

        // Create new curl handle
        $ch=curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user=$cp_user&pass=$cp_pwd");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100020);

        // Execute the curl handle and fetch info then close streams.
        $f = curl_exec($ch);
        $h = curl_getinfo($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        // If we had no issues then try to fetch the cpsess
        if ($f == true and strpos($h['url'],"cpsess"))
        {
            // Get the cpsess part of the url
            $pattern="/.*?(\/cpsess.*?)\/.*?/is";
            $preg_res=preg_match($pattern,$h['url'],$cpsess);
        }

        // If we have a session then return it otherwise return empty string
        return (isset($cpsess[1])) ? $cpsess[1] : "";
    }

    Function fixData($data) {
        $data = str_replace("-","%2D",$data);
        $data = str_replace(".","%2E",$data);
        $data = str_replace(" ","%20",$data);

        return $data;
    }

    Function returnData($data) {
        $data = str_replace("%2D","-",$data);
        $data = str_replace("%2E",".",$data);
        $data = str_replace("%20"," ",$data);

        return $data;
    }
    header('Location: https://www.example.com/users');
?>
```

Comment: hai can you provide the latest cpanel create account code, bcs i couldn't setup this code in my new cpanel : )